# How to handle throttling when using the Azure Translator Text API?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

When I send too many request to the Azure Translator Text API I sometimes receive 429 Responses from the API without indication how to properly throttle the request count. I have found some documentation about throttling but it doesn't seem to apply to this specific API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-request-limits

Does anybody know if there is a similar way to get the remaining request count or the time to wait before another request should be made? Or do I have to implement my own logic to handle throttling?

Comment: you should implement backoff in your code

Comment: I did, but it is not really helping. I guess there is an undocumented hard limit on the number of translation request for a certain time window. If you reach this limit subsequent calls will always fail till the end of that window. i've just discovered that you can send multiple texts up to 5000 characters per request and will go down that route. Still kinda sad that the documentation is lacking.

Comment: What language are you using for your queries? If it is .net, you can still have a look to Polly https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly to manage those cases

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm building on top of the php examples and am using a little script which handles the backoff logic just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Translator Text API is bit specific because the limit announced is not around the number of requests but the number of characters.

As mentioned in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/request-limits#character-limits-per-hour?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365), the limit depends on the type of key:

> Tier / Character limit
>
> - F0: 2 million characters per hour
> - S1: 40 million characters per hour
> - S2: 40 million characters per hour
> - S3: 120 million characters per hour
> - S4: 200 million characters per hour

And I guess that there is also a (more technical) requests limit, not clearly indicated in the documentation

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#errors) states that the api error codes consist of 6 digits. The first digits are equal to the HTTP Response Codes. Exceeding the quota would therefore cause a 403 Response Code and not 429.

Comment: There are 2 errors: one with a 400 and the 6 digit error code, one with a 429. The 429 must be linked to my last line, I will try a to get an answered from the product group

Comment: BTW, I found an interesting sentence in the doc: "There's no limit on the number of outstanding requests to the Translator Text API.", here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/request-limits#character-limits-per-request
 I'm sending my question to the mailing list

Comment: What I wanted to say is that my problem is not the exceeded qouta because I get 429 response codes and not 403. I found that sentence studying the documentation before and I'm not sure what it means, because i surely exceed some kind off request limit when I use the API. Maybe there is a limit of translated characteres per hour because even sending more data per request yields similar throughput for me.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear here the limit of microsoft translator for free tier (F0)

```
2,000,000 million characters per hour/month
33,300 characters per minute
10,000 characters per second/request
```

limit reset 60 seconds after blocked.

Comment: When you reach the 2m chars per month, i assume the API will just fail in the response from there on?